# Terminal becoming unresponsive

Tags: python, terminal

After I run this script:

```
def getVal():
    import sys,tty
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin)  
    key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
    while not (key == 97 or key == 100 or key == 115 or key == 100):
        print("Please enter w, a, s, or d only.")
        key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))

    if key == 119:
        print("Up")
    elif key == 97:
        print("Left")
    elif key == 115:
        print("Down")
    elif key == 100:
        print("Right")
getVal()
```

I try to run it again in terminal but whatever I try to do it won't let me type anything and command c or command z doesn't work(I am on mac). Any way to fix this?

Comment: try cmd-\ to quit

Comment: Also, you should be doing your `import`s at the top of the file, not in your function.

Comment: Also, why call `ord` when you could just compare `key == 'w'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminal is not responsible because your code disabled character echo but forgot to reenable it.

I suggest you store the terminal attributes, and restore them after reading the key:

```
import sys
import tty
import termios

def getVal():
    old = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
    try:
        key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
        while not (key == 97 or key == 100 or key == 115 or key == 119):
            print("Please enter w, a, s, or d only.")
            key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))

        if key == 119:
            print("Up")
        elif key == 97:
            print("Left")
        elif key == 115:
            print("Down")
        elif key == 100:
            print("Right")
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)

getVal()
```